# how to add dynamic data based on condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
groupId  scduleDate
1        '2016-10-5 10:30:00'
2        '2016-10-4 10:30:00'
3        '2016-10-19 10:30:00'
4       '2016-10-19 10:30:00'
```

This is my Table i have to  fetch one column dynamically based on Condition

i am trying using this but i am unable to get Value

```
select groupId,scduleDate
,
case scheduledDate when  >now  then "1"
    else '0'
end
as Real_Title 
from EventList_View
```

my Expected Output is like this :

```
groupId  scduleDate                status
1        '2016-10-5 10:30:00'     0
2        '2016-10-4 10:30:00'     0
3        '2016-10-19 10:30:00'    1
4       '2016-10-19 10:30:00'      1
```

I want-to apply Condition based today date and previous date accordingly i want to add status if previous date from today date it should 0 else 1 
but when i try to execute my query nothing data come please tell me where am doing wrong .

Comment: error in `CASE` expression. Should be like `case when scheduledDate > now`....

Comment: i did same thing also still same issue no data am getting

Comment: select groupId
,
case  when scheduledDate   >now  then "1"
    else '0'
end
as Real_Title 
from EventList_View

Comment: What id the datatype for the column `scduleDate`??

Comment: data type of scduleDate is date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have syntax error in your [*`CASE`*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) expression.

**Query**

```
select groupId,scduleDate,
case when scduleDate > now()  then 1 else 0 end as Real_Title 
from EventList_View;
```

Comment: scduleDate  column  is unknow its telling when i try to excute